# Speeding up filtering function in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file with 400 000 rows and the following headers:

```
header_names = ['LEAGUE', 'YEAR', 'DATE', 'HOME', '1', 'X', '2', 'AWAY', 'SCORE', 'SCORE_1', 'SCORE_2', 'FTR', 'FAVORITE', 'UNDER-OVER']
```

The aim of my function is for every row to take all the previous, filter them by items in the current row and return some statistic.

This is my script so far:

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = 'data.csv'
header_names = ['LEAGUE', 'YEAR', 'DATE', 'HOME', '1', 'X', '2', 'AWAY', 'SCORE', 'SCORE_1', 'SCORE_2', 'FTR', 'FAVORITE', 'UNDER-OVER'] # Add appropriate headers
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', na_values=['', '-'], parse_dates=True, header=None, names=header_names, skiprows=1, nrows=1000)

def mid_func(x):
    global mid
    mid += 1
    return mid

mid = -1
df.insert(0, 'MID', df.apply(mid_func, axis=1))

new_df = df.copy()

def home_1_simple_filter(x):
    mid_stop = x[0] - 1
    home = x[4]
    odd_1 = x[5]
    start = time.time()
    filtered = df[(df['HOME'] == home) & (df['1'] == odd_1)].ix[:mid_stop]['FTR']
    stop = time.time() - start
    print round(stop*1000.,2), 'ms', home, odd_1, mid_stop
    return filtered

start = time.time()
new_df['HOME_1'] = df.apply(home_1_simple_filter, axis=1)
stop = time.time() - start
print stop
```

The `mid_func` is to help me take the previous row. The whole process takes 3 seconds for the first 1000, and 0.002 seconds on average.

Comment: 0.002 seconds per row doesn't seem like much. Do you have some target time in mind? Have you profiled the code to see where the time goes (I would guess that reading in the CSV will be a big chunk of it, which you can't speed up by altering your filter)?

Comment: There will be 60 filter operations like the one I mentioned, for each one of the 400 000 rows, so the overall time needed would be in hours.

Comment: Verify your indentation in `mid_func()`?

Comment: What do you mean about the indentation ?

Comment: @evil_inside indentation is the space before lines